# How to get data and show in a table view from two entity Core data (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entity employee and company. [image]

I have inserted data in both entity. using below methode:

```
func addEmployees() {

    let companyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Company", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let company = Company(entity: companyEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    company.name = txtCompany.text

    let employeesEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employees", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let employees = Employees(entity: employeesEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)        

    employees.name = txtName.text
    employees.empAge = Int(txtAge.text!)
    employees.address = txtAddress.text
//    employees.company = company        
   company.mutableSetValueForKey(EntityName().employee).addObject(employees)

    do {
        try managedContext.save()


    } catch {
        fatalError("Error in saving Data...")
    }
}
```

and retrieved data using this methode:

```
 func fetchCompanyName() {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: EntityName().company)

    if managedContext.countForFetchRequest(request, error: nil) > 0 {

        do {
            let fetchResult = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

            company = fetchResult as! [Company]

        } catch {

            fatalError("Error in fetching company")

        }
    }
}
```

I want to show company name in section header and list of employees in cell. number of section will be equal to company name. i have no idea how to do that???

thanks for help

Comment: You familiar with an `NSFetchedResultsController` and its delegate methods? If you implement one you can set its `sectionNameKeyPath` value to the value of a new attribute (e.g. `sectionIdentifier`) in your entity `Employees`, that you set to `company.name` when you add the new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a fetch request for your companies and then access your employees through its relationship.

```
// Create a fetch Request for all companies.
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: EntityName().company)

// Retrieve an array of companies.
let companies = try! managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Company]

// Ex: Get the employees for the first company.
let firstCompanyEmployees = companies[0].employees
```

Now that you have all your companies in an Array, you just have to populate your `UITableView` header's with your `company.name` and each `UITableViewCell` content with the employee information.

Remember that you must conform to the [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/) protocol to provide the necessary information such as: the [title](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:) for each section and the [content](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) for the cells.

Hope that helps :)